# How to make an object point in its movement direction? (BGE)

Tags: game-engine, transforms, logic-bricks

I tried to do it in with actuators, but so far either the animation gets stuck, or it hangs up on a direction if you let go of one of the keys. Help?

Edit: I added the logic I'm using so far. The actions are displaying one frame of the rotate animation, each frame is a different rotation. This was my workaround for the question above, but when I hold down and right, and let go of right, it stays in the same orientation but goes downwards. Is there any way I can either fix this setup, or is there a way I can make the object point in the direction it moves?

Edit #2: I changed the program, making a logic brick for each key, and another for each one not being pressed. It works, going left or right makes the block display the up/down frame but then quickly changes to the left/right frame. Also, The jumping doesn't seem to work moving diagonally, except when moving up and to the right. If you could take a look at the blend file and let me know what I did wrong, that would be great.

[image]

Comment: Please provide more information from your logic configuration, some images and/or scripts so we can help you.

Comment: I have now edited the post to clarify.

Comment: Have you try activating ``Add`` in all action actuators?

Comment: Also you can provide a blend (if you want to) through [https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/), copy and paste the link in your question.

Comment: Alright, I made another edit and incorporated the blend file. I rewrote the logic bricks for the cube as per the edit details.

Comment: I found really hard to work with your file since everything was rotated, i made new one just placing the camera where it need to be to achieve the look you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made it diferent as you was doing it but i think its more easy this way.

Instead using animation i add 8 cubes rounding the cube player and make them vertex parented with no collition physics and add 8 `edit object actuator` set to `track to` for each cube.

[image]

Abd here the blend.
[image]

Comment: I edited my logic in the way you suggested and..... it worked! Thanks for the help!

Comment: You can download the blend that i made for a more closer look.